# compute a quaternion then convert it to matrix, but when i multiply this matrix it becomes very weird

Tags: opengl, matrix, quaternions, glm-math

i want to rotate a cube so first i compute a quaternion, convert it into a rotatematrix, then multiplies it with the vertex, is that right?

i did that with glm.hpp, but the rotation of the cube is very weird when the rotationaxis was not (0,1,0) or (1,0,1) or (0,0,1).

the code goes like this:

```
glm::vec3 rotationAxis = glm::normalize((glm::cross(glm::vec3(0,1,1), glm::vec3(1,1,0))));
    GLfloat cosAngle = glm::dot(glm::normalize(glm::vec3(0, 1, 1)), glm::normalize(glm::vec3(1, 1, 0)));
    GLfloat s = glm::sqrt((1 + cosAngle) * 2);
    GLfloat invs = 1 / s;
    glm::quat rotationQuat = glm::quat(
        s * 0.5f,
        rotationAxis.x * invs,
        rotationAxis.y * invs,
        rotationAxis.z * invs);
    glm::mat4 matTemp = glm::mat4_cast(rotationQuat);
    ArcballMatrix = matTemp*ArcballMatrix;
```

and the vertexshader goes like this:

```
gl_Position = projection * view * ArcballMatrix * vec4(vertexPosition, 1.0f);
```

did i miss something?

Comment: why not `glm::normalize(glm::quat(cosAngle+1, rotationAxis.x, rotationAxis.y, rotationAxis.z));`

Comment: cool, it worked, but still i don't know why, can u explain to me where did i go wrong or just give me a link or something? thank u very much. @ratchetfreak

Comment: everything works well after I replace  the glm::quat with glm::angleAxis